# Update txt file with file_get_content

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$fisier = file_get_contents('urlproxy'); // Read the file with the proxy list
$linii = explode("\n", $fisier); // Get each proxy
$fisier = fopen("bune.txt", "a"); // Here we will write the good ones
```

I need every time I run the script it rewrites the txt file only with the new proxy.

Can someone help me?

Comment: OK… so what is your question? It sounds like you've already figured out what to do.

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: Only repeating your question does not explain what your concrete issue is. Any errors? What happens? Also you could just do `copy("http:/…", "file.txt");`

Comment: @mario, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fopen` with `'a'` mode. According to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters):

> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
> file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode,
> fseek() has no effect, **writes are always appended**.

So, you need to use `'w'` mode. Like this:

```
$fisier = fopen("bune.txt", "w");
```